# Legality of UN sanctions against North Korea

Tags: united-nations, nuclear-weapons, north-korea, sanctions

From a [Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/apr/23/north-korea-launched-offshore-ballistic-missile-says-the-south): "North Korea is banned from nuclear tests .... under UN sanctions dating 2006 and most recently ..."

What is the exact relation between UN and North Korea ?

Where comes the UN jurisdiction over North Korea from ?

Comment: can you link your cited article, please?

Comment: [Stop war drills and we'll stop nuclear tests, North Korea tells US after missile launch](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/apr/23/north-korea-launched-offshore-ballistic-missile-says-the-south), last paragraph

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The jurisdiction of the UN is derived from the fact that North Korea joined the United Nations in 1991. UN resolutions are binding for all member-states. Enforcement of UN resolutions is usually not done through force but rather through sanctions. Sanctions usually mean that countries refuse to trade or cooperate in other ways with the violating country.

Comment: Not to mention it signed a treaty agreeing to the terms in 1998 that is has repeately ignroed.